# Groupby.count in pandas with conditions

Tags: count, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I have weather data from 13 years, with 154 days each year (only interested in summer days), from which I would like to get the number of dry days occurred each year. This means I have a great data (df) set that I want to shrink (df_Ch). I've already done with the total rain per year:

```
df_Ch = df.groupby(by = ["distrito", "year"], as_index=False)["Chuvia"].sum()
```

I'm now trying with total dry days per year:

```
df_Ds = df.groupby(by = ["distrito", "year"], as_index=False)[when "Chuvia" == 0].count()
```

Of course, it didn't work
I spent some hours without success trying to get something... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the condition before  using `groupby`, so you will already have your "filtered" df before grouping it.

```
df_Ds = df[df["Chuvia" == 0]].groupby(by = ["distrito", "year"], as_index=False)["Chuvia"].count()
```